# Is it possible to lock different areas of a monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, locking

I'm working with multithreading and this is my scenario.

- Multiple threads are running
- The threads have to access different methods in a monitor
- These methods don't collide with one another and don't touch the same resources
- Can I lock different methods/areas in the monitor?

The code below is just an example of what I'm trying to do, but I hope it communicates my main issue.
I have multiple threads running and two ArrayLists in the Monitor (not in the example code below though). The two methods work on the two different ArrayLists, but one method doesn't touch the other one and vice versa. Will I lose parallelity if I do it this way?

So this is the Monitor-code:

```java
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
    
    public class Monitor{
        Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
        Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();
    
        public void loopLiten(Integer ID, String type){
            try{
                lock1.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " does a small loop.");
                for(Integer i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error.");
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is done making a  " + type + " loop.");
                lock1.unlock();
            }
        }
    
        public void loopStor(Integer ID, String type){
            try{
                lock2.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " does a bigger loop.");
                for(Integer i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error.");
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is done making a " + type + " loop.");
                lock2.unlock();
            }   
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been discussed in the comments your code is already making use of explicit locks and doing it that way is fine. As long as the code using the 2 locks doesn't operate on the same data there shouldn't be any problem.

Note, however, that access to the same data can happen further down "the road", i.e. depending on what you are doing in your loops you could still get racing conditions etc.
Imagine your separate array lists contain the same instances and both methods are accessing those instances - that could lead to concurrency issues.

Finally a note on "monitor" in Java: monitor objects are used in conjunction with `synchronized`, i.e. you don't acquire explicit locks on those. Instead whenever you enter a synchronized block the runtime will try to lock the associated monitor behind the scenes. There are basically 2 flavors of `synchronized` blocks:

- methods like `synchronized void runLocked()` where the enclosing instance or class (for static methods) is the associated monitor object
- synchronized blocks which can operate on different monitor objects but require those to be explicitly set, e.g. `synchronized(this) { ... }` or `synchronized(someObject)`.

To fully synchronize a certain object's methods you'd make those synchronized methods but if you need to synchronize on parts of an object you'd need to use synchronized blocks with different monitor objects (can just be instances of `Object`) or explictly use locks like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

> The threads have to access different methods in a monitor

The monitor is *just* an Object used to [ensure mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) on the access to a given resource/block of code.

> - These methods don't collide with one another and don't touch the same
>   resources
> - Can I lock different methods/areas in the monitor?

The question should actually be "can I use different locks to lock those separate resources".

You can create a lock *per* resource(s) that you want to ensure *mutual exclusion*. If the methods work with different resources then you can use a finer grain locking approach (i.e., locking *per* single resource), naturally this depends from code to code.

> I have multiple threads running and two ArrayLists in the Monitor (not
> in the example code below though). The two methods work on the two
> different ArrayLists, but one method doesn't touch the other one and
> vice versa.

If those Lists are shared among threads and are concurrently updated, then you should ensure thread-safely by (for instance) using an explicit lock *per* resource.

> Will I lose parallelity if I do it this way?

No actually you will gain some. Adding a locking mechanism will naturally reduce the amount of computation that can be done in parallel. However, by creating separate locks *per* List you ensure that 2 threads that are working on different lists can work in parallel. If you only had one lock for both lists then 2 threads could not work simultaneously on those two separate Lists.